# How to tell gradle / Android Studio to not let downloaded dependencies expire

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

**Summary**

I program a rather low maintenance app. Sometimes I do not open Android Studio for months before I want to change a line of code or two.

Everytime I do open Android Studio all dependencies seemingly vanished. That wouldn't be a problem if everything would work after syncing gradle. But somehow it is never that easy.

**Bckground**

Last time gradle just did not redownload some of them. I had to update the version numbers which led to adding androidX which led to updating all other libraries whose older versions depended on the older support libs and **that** necessitated running through migration guides of some of the updated libs.

And after all that I needed to fix the bugs those migrations caused. 
On the plus side: The app is up to date.

I still needed far too much time for changing a single line of code.

I tried to find a way to configure gradle in such a way that it just does not delete/invalidate libs after a certain amount of time. I only found ways how to force a redownload.

But I don't want gradle to download anything. I want that my development environment remains the same even after months of not using it.

So: **Is it possible to confgure gradle / Android Studio in such a way that projects are still in working condition even after not using them for months?**

Comment: Preference -> Build -> Gradle -> Offline Work
Simple check the Offline Work, and don't forget that if you're running other projects and accidentally invalidate cache or uncheck Offline Work, it might have to redownload.....this is more like a hack.

Comment: You can update the dependencies as you required.